# Oracle forms run form applet but not response

Tags: linux, oracle, oracleforms

We have a software build using Oracle Forms.   We need to deploy the software on Linux(UBUNTU) server.  The software runs the form in the web browser successfully , the problem is that the software is not responding.  We can press (click) buttons but the software not seem to work although no exception appears.

The Windows server ran it without any problems.  We suspect that the problem happens because of LINUX/UNIX systems are case sensitives ?!

Any suggestions ?

Comment: are any warning\error messages shown in the Oracle Forms Java Console?

Comment: Have you tried enabling tracing for the forms session? That might help generate the logs necessary for finding the failure.

Comment: Are you using Sun Java or Jinitiator? What version? What browser (I assume firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

"We can press (click) buttons but the software not seem to work although no exception appears.
We suspect that the problem happens because of LINUX/UNIX systems are case sensitives ?!"

Possible, depending on what the buttons are supposed to do.

*nix filenames are case-sensitive, so if the code it doing a CALL_FORM('a123') then windows will execute A123 whereas *nix will not.

However if it doing something like throwing an alert message, displaying (or undisplaying) an item or inserting a row into the database, then the case-sensitivity shouldn't come into it.

Did you get any issues when you recompiled the forms source code for Linux ?